# Plugin which unlock free gift when you reach some amount in cart

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a plugin which adds product to cart when you reach some amount in cart, now I need to add a product thumbnail to visualise it.
Ihave created a wordpress setting where you putting an id of a present

```
        add_settings_field(
      'tier_1_present',
      '1st Present product ID',
      'panam_render_tier_1_present_field',
      'panam_example_plugin',
      'section_one'
    );
```

So, can I somehow use it to show what product will be added to cart using product summary or smthng

Here is my code

```
        if ($panam_subtotal <= $tier_1_present_price) {
        $percent = number_format((WC()->cart->get_subtotal()/$tier_1_present_price)*100, 2, '.', '');

        $price_to_free_gift = number_format( $tier_1_present_price - $panam_subtotal, 2, '.', '');
        
        $html .= '<div class="gift_progress_wrap" style="display:block;height: auto;">
            <span id="progress_free_gift" class="progress_title_gift">
                <span id="progress_price_gift">'.$price_to_free_gift.'</span> <span class="txt">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(). __( 'to get your TIER 1 free gift', 'present_box' ).'</span>
            </span> 
            
            <div class="progress_bar_free_gift">
                <div class="fill" style="width:'.$percent.'%; height:10px; background-color:crimson;"></div>
            </div></div>';;
            
            
    } elseif ($panam_subtotal > $tier_1_present_price) {

        $panam_product_cart_id_tier1 = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($tier_1_present);   
        if (!WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart($panam_product_cart_id_tier1) && $panam_subtotal > $tier_1_present_price) {               
                
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart($tier_1_present);   
        }
        $html .= '<div class="gift_progress_wrap" style="display:block;height: auto;">
            <span id="progress_free_gift" class="progress_title_gift">
                <span id="progress_price_gift"></span> <span class="txt">' . __( 'You have unlocked your TIER 1 free gift', 'present_box' ).'</span>
            </span>
            
            <div class="progress_bar_free_gift">
                <div class="fill" style="width:100%; height:15px; background-color:green;"></div>
            </div></div>';;
        
    }
```

The idea is to show customer what product he will receive if will spend more money, for now its only loading bar and progress bar. I need to add product price and product picture to it, screenshot attached.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question to make clear what your specific question is? Would also be good to know what you've already tried / where it is failing you and specifically what you expect.

Comment: The idea is to show customer what product he will receive if will spend more money, for now its only loading bar and progress bar. I need to add product price and product picture to it, screenshot attached. Thanks

Comment: I was trying to use standard constructor like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277990/how-to-display-product-summary-by-id